# How to add an Element sortOption to sort by number?

Tags: elementtype, elementquery

I have an Element. It's a Structure, with one level (not sure if that is relevant). I'd like to add a Sort Option that allows a user to sort the Element Index page for this Element by a number. The number attribute is stored in the database as an `int` and named `count`.

On the Element class, I can add a way to sort the Element by a row alphabetically:

```
protected static function defineSortOptions(): array
{
  $attributes = [
    'someTextField' => Craft::t('my-plugin', 'Some Text Field')
  ]
}
```

However, I haven't yet been able to figure out how to give the option to sort by a number:

```
protected static function defineSortOptions(): array
{
  $attributes = [
    'someTextField' => Craft::t('my-plugin', 'Some Text Field'),
    'count' => Craft::t('my-plugin', 'Count')
  ]
}
```

The above example does not work. I've also explored the non-shorthand syntax that I see in the Craft Commerce Subscription sort options, however, have been unable to figure out how to adjust things to work with numbers.

```
protected static function defineSortOptions(): array
{
    return [
        [
            'label' => Craft::t('commerce', 'Subscription date'),
            'orderBy' => 'commerce_subscriptions.dateCreated',
            'attribute' => 'dateCreated'
        ],
    ];
}
```

How can I allow a user to order an Element Index page by a numeric column?

Comment: Did you define `count` as tableattribute as well?

Comment: Yep. ```public static function defineTableAttributes($source = null): array
    {
        return [
            'count' => Craft::t('my-plugin', 'Count')
        ];
    }```

Comment: I'm not totally sure if that's really the issue but maybe it could have something to do with the word `count` in yii2 and queries. I'll investigate more time in a few hours but maybe you could try to rename it to `count2` or something else and see if it solves the issue. In general there is no difference between text and number columns in the DB. Just a question for now: what didn't work? Was the column not sortable or did it throw an exception?

Comment: No errors, It's just that the column does not sort anything. It always displays the same order.